# JS/TS - Returning promise resolved/rejected values inside async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I am using a function definition in my code which is an async function and it returns values from a Promise with try/catch. Something like this :-

```js
async someFunction(parameters) {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try {

      // do something like an api call with await and resolve the response
      resolve(parameters);

    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}

someFunction("HEllo world");
```

I wanted to ask, is this overkill? am i writing redundant code? is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Depends on what's inside the `do something`

Comment: @CertainPerformance updated the code.

Comment: Yes, it's at least two anti-patterns.  You don't need to declare a function `async` that you're just returning a manually created promise from.  And, you don't need to declare the promise executor callback as `async` either.  And, if you're using `await` inside the executor, then you don't need to wrap it with a manually created promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 what if i am calling this function elsewhere with await?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to ask, is this overkill? am i writing redundant code? is this an anti-pattern?

Yes, it's overkill and it's at least two, maybe three anti-patterns.

You don't need to declare a function `async` that you're just returning a manually created promise from.  And, you don't need to declare the promise executor callback as `async` either.  And, if you're using `await` inside the executor, then you don't need to wrap it with a manually created promise.

If you're really planning on using `await` inside the promise executor, then you must already have functions that return promises that you want to use `await` with.  If that's the case, then there's no reason to wrap those in a manually created promise.  That is a promise anti-pattern.

You also don't need to try/catch and then just reject with the same error. You can just let the error propagate on its own.

So, let's suppose you have two promise-returning functions that you want to run serially using `await`.  Then, all you need is this:

```
async function someFunction(parameters) {

    let v1 = await func1(...);
    // do something with v1
    let v2 = await func2(someValFromV1);
    // do something with v2
    return someValFromV2;
}

someFunction("HEllo world").then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Or you can call it with `await` instead of `.then()`:

```
async function anotherFunction() {
    let result = await someFunction(...);
    // do something with result
}
```

Comment: As i commented above, what if i am calling this function somewhere else with await? i should then define the function as async, right? Also, i am performing tasks related to DB (most DB ORM functions return a promise), or external API calls, inside someFunction and i need to return errors if the functions fail. What should i do in that case? For information, i am making a web app and i need to show errors or values returned in the response.

Comment: @Gabriel - My answer already shows calling it with `await` at the end.  This hypothetical stuff described in words makes good answers really hard.  If you want more specific help, then show us your REAL code and we'll be able to give you very specific (and probably helpful) advice.  The best way to code asynchronous code is always specific to exactly what you're doing and would take a book to cover all the theoretical possibilities.  But, can easily show you a good way if you show us a SPECIFIC piece of real code.

Comment: @Gabriel - All my examples automatically propagate errors back through the returned promise.  A rejected promise on an `await` error causes the promise returns from the `async` function to reject automatically and the caller sees that rejection with the appropriate error.  Only if you want to intercept the error and do something special when it happens do you need to catch the error locally rather than just let it naturally propagate back to the caller.  REAL code would be much easier to discuss.